# Templating a template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, fmt

I have the following template to use `fmt` to format a user-defined type:

```
#include "fmt/format.h"

struct MyClass
{
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return "xyz";
    }
};

template <> struct fmt::formatter<MyClass>
{
    template <typename ParseContext> constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) const {
        return ctx.begin();
    }
    template <typename FormatContext> constexpr auto format(const MyClass& c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", (std::string)c);
    }
};
```

I attempted to template and instantiate this template specialization:

```
template <typename T> template <> struct fmt::formatter<T>
{
    template <typename ParseContext> constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) const {
        return ctx.begin();
    }
    template <typename FormatContext> constexpr auto format(const T& t, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", (std::string)t);
    }
};

template struct fmt::formatter<MyClass>;
```

I get `error C2913: explicit specialization; 'fmt::v7::formatter<MyClass,char,void>' is not a specialization of a class template`.

How can I accomplish this, or some other way to make it simpler to turn a type with overloaded `operator std::string()` into a type that can be formatted?

Comment: Concepts in C++20, SFINAE before that. What you attempted to do is just the same as the template definition, it doesn't constrain `T` in any way.

Comment: [Example using C++20 concepts](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5590373a9fd067bf)

Comment: Alas, I am on C++17.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have re-usable formatter that you can explicitly define for any class, the easiest thing to do would be to define a base class and derive `fmt::formatter<T>` from it:

```
template <typename T>
struct StringCastFormatter
{
    template <typename ParseContext> constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) const {
        return ctx.begin();
    }
    template <typename FormatContext> constexpr auto format(const T& c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", (std::string)c);
    }
};

template <>
struct fmt::formatter<MyClass> : StringCastFormatter<MyClass> {};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/145b079aa21f1780)

---

If instead you want to define a formatter that automatically applies to any class that can be converted to `std::string`, then you need to use either C++20 concepts or some form of SFINAE.

Possible C++20 concepts implementation:

```
template <std::convertible_to<std::string> T>
struct fmt::formatter<T>
{
    template <typename ParseContext> constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) const {
        return ctx.begin();
    }
    template <typename FormatContext> constexpr auto format(const T& c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", (std::string)c);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5590373a9fd067bf)

And a possible C++17 SFINAE-based solution:

```
template <typename T, typename...>
using First = T;

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<First<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>>>>
{
    template <typename ParseContext> constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) const {
        return ctx.begin();
    }
    template <typename FormatContext> constexpr auto format(const T& c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", (std::string)c);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b300206b9f3472)

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I tried the StringCastFormatter and got `error C3861: 'format_to': identifier not found`.

Comment: The SFINAE-based solution works unless I use a char array of length 8 or greater as fmt argument (or string literal; char pointer is fine though). E.g. fmt::format("{}", "abcabcabc") yields `error C2752: 'fmt::v7::formatter<char [3],char,void>': more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list \ note: could be 'fmt::v7::formatter<Char[N],Char,void>' \ note: or 'fmt::v7::formatter<T,char,void>'`.

Comment: I wonder if fmt's `has_formatter` could be used to restrict the template to types that don't have a formatter yet.
`template <typename T, typename Context>
using has_formatter =
    std::is_constructible<typename Context::template formatter_type<T>>;`